# IE ignores !important tag in css

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Recently I came across a wierd thing in IE.

It ignores a '!important' tag for CSS attributes.

Does anyone have a workaround for this, except putting it directly as a style attribute inside the DOM?

I do not want to go into the DOM and put styling attributes in it.

Comment: it is !important not !iportant, maybe your have made typo in your script

Comment: IE supports `!important`. You'll need to be more specific about how to reproduce the problem. (As a rule of thumb, if you are using `!important` then you've done something wrong. Getting the specificity of your rules correct is usually the right approach to any problem that `!important` looks like the answer to)

Comment: !important rules are more or less hacks actually, try to avoid them, try conditional comments instead

Comment: True @Quentin.  But sometimes `!important` is necessary when dealing with legacy code and / or templates that cannot be manipulated.

Comment: Then you are hacking around the real problem — which is that your legacy code needs refactoring or you need access to the templates. ;D I did say it was only a rule of thumb.

Comment: @Justus - !important rules are not hacks, but they are horribly misused. CSS2.1 (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) makes clear what they're for - allowing a balance of control between author and user style sheets. They're fine for that purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the `!important` tag will not work in a style if it has previously been used on the style that you are trying to overwrite/update.

For example, if you have:

```
.example{
color:#ff0000 !important;
}
```

And, say for example, if your using [Media Queries](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) and tell the style to change upon the browser being reduced in size:

```
.example{
color:#fff !important;
}
```

The secondary colr `#fff` won't take affect because of the `!important` assigned to the color `#ff0000`.

Just an observation/thought.

It's pretty hard to guess what is causing the issue. For the users of SO to really help you, you will have to either supply a *live link*, sample code on [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) or post your **HTML** and **CSS** in the question.