# Visited links not changing color in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have the CSS below affecting news entries automatically populated through javascript, and :visited is not persisting through page refresh on IE(any version), but is persisting on Chrome/FF.  Does anyone know why IE would have issues retaining visited attribute?

```
.Hyperlinks:visited {
    color:#2c3c4f!important;
}

.Hyperlinks:hover {
    color:#f39b13!important;
}
```

The HTML it is affecting:

```
<div class='panel' style='margin:0; padding-left: 10px; background:white; color:#0072C5'>
<h4 style='margin-bottom:0; padding-left:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; color:#0072C5' id='newsTitle'>
<a class='Hyperlinks' style='color:blue;' target='_blank' href='my_link_here'></a></h4>
<p></p></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visited Links color not changing in IE 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620122/visited-links-color-not-changing-in-ie-8)

Comment: That says that in recent browsers they have re-enabled the style, meaning I shouldn't have that issue in IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the reason was not the CSS or HTML at all, but rather than the Hyperlink was making a small redirect. So when you travel to the link, Chrome and Firefox must have recorded both the pre and post redirect links, whereas Internet Explorer does not, so that link would show up as having never been visited.

Answer (score 1):

As of IE8 visited should be supported [visited Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848869(v=vs.85).aspx) but since IE always has to be different and weird it DOES NOT support !important. Refer here for [!important issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126893/ie-ignores-important-tag-in-css)

Hope that helps.